# health slider not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a `crystal match 3` game using Unity3d.

I added the `Health` feature. It doesn't work properly. Everytime I change the `energie`, it goes to 0. I tried to reduce it by `-10` from the initial value of `100`.

Can you help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class score : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Slider energieSlider;
    public static int points = 0;
    public static int level = 1;
    public static int stars = 0;
    public static int die = 0;
    public static int tap = 0;
    public static int start = 0;
    public static int Score = 0;
    public static int share = 0;
    public static int login = 0;

    public static int energie = 100;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text levelText;
    public Text starsText;
    public static int totalpoints = 0;

    public void addhealth()
    {
        energieSlider.value += 100;
    }

    public void removehealth()
    {
        energieSlider.value -= 10;
        energie -= 10;
        points = 0;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    //public void onClickScoreButton () 
    //{
        //points++;
    //}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + points;
        levelText.text = "Level: " + level;
        starsText.text = "Stars: " + stars;

        totalpoints += points;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalpoints", + totalpoints);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", totalpoints);

        if (points >= 1000) 
        {
            totalpoints += points;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalpoints", + totalpoints);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", totalpoints);
            stars += 1;

            Invoke("removehealth", 0f);

            points = 0;

            //energieSlider.value = energie;
        }

        if (stars == 3) 
        {
            level += 1;
            //call archiment scene

            //points = 0;

            totalpoints = points;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalpoints", totalpoints);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", points);

            Application.LoadLevel("Cristals Scores");
        }

        //if (totalpoints == 1001) 
        //{
            //energie -= 10;
            //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tap", tap);
        //}

        if (energieSlider.value <= 0) 
        {
            die += 1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("die", die);
            //wait 3 secs
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            //game over scene
            Application.LoadLevel("gameover");
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        energieSlider.value = 1000;
        //if (energieSlider != null)
        //{
            //energieSlider.IsActive();
        //}
        totalpoints = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalpoints");

        tap = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tap");
        die = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("die");
        start = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("start");
        stars = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("stars");
        //totalpoints = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
        energie = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("energie");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are giving points to the player but I see you have

```
totalpoints += points;
```

just sitting outside above the if statement in your update. That value is growing constantly every frame.

Try using `Debug.Log("The Points: " + points);` in your update and watch what happens.